# Find x in a given arithmetic sequence with known sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have an arithmetic sequence $-3 + 1 + 5 + 9 + \cdots + x$ which has the sum of $150$.

I know that formula for the sum of arithmetic sequence is $n \left ( \frac{a_{1} + a_{n}}{2} \right )$ but I don't know how to find $x$ when I don't know neither it's position nor it's value which is needed for formula.

Comment: $a_{1}=-3,$ and $x=a_{n}=-3+4(n-1).$

Comment: for what stands $x$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Pardon, I tend to mix up programming and math. It's the last element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hint provided by RideTheWavelet and then use the formula you gave for the sum of an arithmetic sequence.

$150=\frac{n}{2}(-3+a_n)=\frac{n}{2}[-3+-3+4(n-1)]=\frac{n}{2}(-10+4n)=-5n+2n^2$

Solving the quadratic equation $150=-5n+2n^2$ gives $n=-7.5$ and $n=10$. Of course, only the latter makes sense.

Then $x=a_n=-3+4(10-1)=33$.